# Best practice when using OpenIddict application properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, .net-6.0, openiddict

I'm using the `Properties` column in my OpenIddict applications to store some metadata about an application instead of using a custom entity - comments on this post [custom properties within token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60326649/custom-properties-within-token) imply that's what its meant for.

However, despite reading the above post I'm struggling to understand how best to implement this.

Currently my "create application" looks like this:

```
public interface IOpenIddictAppService
{
    Task<CreateOpenIddictAppResponseDto> CreateAsync(CreateOpenIddictAppRequestDto appDto);
}

public class OpenIddictAppService : IOpenIddictAppService
{
    private readonly IOpenIddictApplicationManager _appManager;

    public OpenIddictAppService(IOpenIddictApplicationManager appManager)
    {
        _appManager = appManager;
    }

    public async Task<CreateOpenIddictAppResponseDto> CreateAsync(CreateOpenIddictAppRequestDto appDto)
    {
        var sha = SHA512.Create();
        var clientId = Convert.ToBase64String(sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())));
        var clientSecret = SecureRandomStringHelper.Create(StaticData.ClientSecretSize);

        var data = new OpenIddictApplicationDescriptor
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            ClientSecret = clientSecret,
            DisplayName = appDto.Name,
            Permissions =
            {
                OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Endpoints.Token,
                OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Prefixes.Scope + "api",
                OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.ResponseTypes.Code
            }
        };

        // Postman test URL"https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback"
        appDto.RedirectUrls.Split(" ").ToList().ForEach(x => data.RedirectUris.Add(new Uri(x)));
        data.Properties.Add("IdentityConfig", JsonSerializer.SerializeToElement(new AppIdentityProperties
        {
            ClientSystemId = appDto.ClientSystemId,
            CustomerAccountId = appDto.CustomerAccountId
        }));

        var app = await _appManager.CreateAsync(data);

        CreateOpenIddictAppResponseDto result = new()
        {
            Id = new Guid(await _appManager.GetIdAsync(app) ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("OpenIddictApplication not found")),
            ClientId = clientId, // Send back the client id used
            ClientSecret = clientSecret, // Send back the secret used so it can be displayed one-time-only for copy/paste
            RedirectUrls = string.Join(" ", await _appManager.GetRedirectUrisAsync(app))
        };

        return result;
    }
}
```

And I'm loading it like this in my authorization controller:

```
[HttpPost("~/connect/token")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Exchange()
{
    var request = HttpContext.GetOpenIddictServerRequest() ??
                  throw new InvalidOperationException("The OpenID Connect request cannot be retrieved.");

    ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal;

    if (request.IsClientCredentialsGrantType())
    {
        // Note: the client credentials are automatically validated by OpenIddict:
        // if client_id or client_secret are invalid, this action won't be invoked.

        var application = await _applicationManager.FindByClientIdAsync(request.ClientId);
        if (application == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The application details cannot be found in the database.");
        }

        // Create the claims-based identity that will be used by OpenIddict to generate tokens.
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
            authenticationType: TokenValidationParameters.DefaultAuthenticationType,
            nameType: Claims.Name,
            roleType: Claims.Role);

        // Add the claims that will be persisted in the tokens (use the client_id as the subject identifier).
        identity.AddClaim(Claims.Subject, await _applicationManager.GetClientIdAsync(application))
                .AddClaim(Claims.Name, await _applicationManager.GetDisplayNameAsync(application));

        var properties = await _applicationManager.GetPropertiesAsync(application);
        if (properties.Any(o => o.Key == "IdentityConfig"))
        {
            var identityConfig = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AppIdentityProperties>(properties.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Key == "IdentityConfig").Value);
            if (identityConfig != null)
            {
                identity.AddClaim(StaticData.Claims.ClientSystem, identityConfig.ClientSystemId.ToString())
                        .AddClaim(StaticData.Claims.CustomerAccount, identityConfig.CustomerAccountId.ToString());
            }
        }

        identity.SetDestinations(static claim => claim.Type switch
        {
            // Allow the "name" claim to be stored in both the access and identity tokens
            // when the "profile" scope was granted (by calling principal.SetScopes(...)).
            Claims.Name when claim.Subject.HasScope(Scopes.Profile)
                => new[] { Destinations.AccessToken, Destinations.IdentityToken },

            // Otherwise, only store the claim in the access tokens.
            _ => new[] { Destinations.AccessToken }
        });

        // Note: In the original OAuth 2.0 specification, the client credentials grant
        // doesn't return an identity token, which is an OpenID Connect concept.
        //
        // As a non-standardized extension, OpenIddict allows returning an id_token
        // to convey information about the client application when the "openid" scope
        // is granted (i.e specified when calling principal.SetScopes()). When the "openid"
        // scope is not explicitly set, no identity token is returned to the client application.

        // Set the list of scopes granted to the client application in access_token.
        claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        claimsPrincipal.SetScopes(request.GetScopes());

        claimsPrincipal.SetResources(await _scopeManager.ListResourcesAsync(claimsPrincipal.GetScopes()).ToListAsync());
    }
    else if (request.IsAuthorizationCodeGrantType())
    {
        // Retrieve the claims principal stored in the authorization code
        claimsPrincipal = (await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)).Principal;
    }
    else if (request.IsRefreshTokenGrantType())
    {
        // Retrieve the claims principal stored in the refresh token.
        claimsPrincipal = (await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)).Principal;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The specified grant type is not supported.");
    }

    // Returning a SignInResult will ask OpenIddict to issue the appropriate access/identity tokens.
    return SignIn(claimsPrincipal, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}
```

Now - it's working...but I have a sneaky feeling that I'm just using it wrong especially based on Kevin Chalet's comments on that post... I think I'm probably also setting the redirect URLs the wrong way too!

Can anyone give me any more specific guidance on how I should really be doing this.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for posting this. Are you know more familiar with this? I am in the need of learning more about it. Thanks!